# Efficient rotating tray with 4 slots

Tags: algorithm, math

I have a circle divided into fourths. I need an algorithm that can rotate the circle from one position to another in the most efficient way.

The "trays" are named 1 to 4.

I now use the algoritm:

```
int degrees = (currentPos - newPos) * 90;
```

using the algorithm i get how many degrees i need to rotate the circle to get to the new position. However if i am in position 4 and need to go to 1, the result will be 4 - 1 * 90 = 270. In this case the most efficient would be to rotate -90 instead of 270. (the same goes for moving from 1 to 4).

Anyone got a good idea of how to do this? I can of course use an if statement:

```
       if(degrees >= -180 && degrees <= 180) 
       sortingTrayMotor.rotate(degrees);
    else if(degrees == -270)
       sortingTrayMotor.rotate(90);
    else
        sortingTrayMotor.rotate(-90);
```

I guess there is a better way to do it though with some mod operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly what you're doing, only if the result is > 180 degrees, subtract 360 degrees.